# PHP order by clause with array as order by statement

Tags: mysql, arrays, list, select

I got a array with a query

This array is ordered by criteria.

Now I want to make a new query

Sample

```
$array = (987, 2661, 12, 789, 54);
```

And I want in this order by array selecting articles

```
select * from article a.number WHERE (a.number IN ($array))
```

How can I realize that this result is ordered by $array ids?

Thx you 4 answer guys :)

edit :

```
Article Table:
id, name etc..

Property Table:

id, article_id, name, value

1,        10,   journey_days, 2
2,        30,   journey_days, 1
3,        40,   journey_days, 5
1,        10,   stars,        2
2,        10,   stars,        4
3,        10,   stars,        0
4,        10,   stars,        1
```

I join both tables, but as you can see the property have more then one value per column for one article.

I need to join the Property table to the article table and get all Values there are related from property table to the article, if I make a where clause I just get stars or journey_days.

How can I realise this? to select all property.name values with a where or on clause?

Hope you guys understand my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$s = implode(",", $array);
$q = "select * from article a.number WHERE (a.number IN ($s))";
```

Comment: the question is , how get result ordered by number in array ?

Comment: I am afraid that's not possible. You could get each record in its own `SELECT`, or introduce some kind of `orderby` column.

Comment: i got 2 queries one that order by colum and get the ids back and put them into a array
and then i want to get articles by this array list

Comment: @Wykk why not join these two tables and have only one query?

Comment: this doesnt work coz one colum have more then 1 property in and i have to where = property in colum, so i dont get all properties this is why i trhy to make one query for ids order and then select all ids with all properties..

Comment: coz of the where clausle i cant join this so easy.. :(

Comment: If you get a list of ids, you can join with those IDs

Comment: could you make me a explain?
I dont get it imo, i joining 3 tables to get the right id order 
and one of the joins is a property table 
and then i want to get all from articles in that order. 
Should i join article table 2 times? 
A example would be nice ;) thx in regards

Comment: @Wykk If you could repost that question, people will help you. And it is perfectly valid to join a table multiple time, or even join a table with itself.

Comment: @ Barts Friederichs this works for me, i join two times the property and one time i gief him a on p.name = 'hotel' clause
and in the second i get all colums with a inner join to the article Table so i can order by my value column. Thx man you made my day!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could construct a `CASE` expression and order by that, but it's probably better to do this in PHP, outside of the database.

```
... ORDER BY CASE a.number 
         WHEN 987   THEN 1
         WHEN 2661  THEN 2
         WHEN 12    THEN 3
         WHEN 789   THEN 4 
         WHEN 54    THEN 5
         END;
```

Or you could use the `FIND_IN_SET` function:

```
.... ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(a.number, "987,2661,12,789,54");
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? As far as I can tell this answers the question perfectly.